# how to set arraylist object to table using OOP concept

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, arraylist, jtable

I have create an `OrderModel` object inside the method for getting values from DB and set it to `JTable`. I want to know how to set this created object to `JTable` using this code:

```
 tblOrderItems.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel());
```

and this is my code:

```
private void tblOrderListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
      int raw = tblOrderList.getSelectedRow();
      OrderModel or;
      String item;
      Double qty,amount,total;

      ArrayList<OrderModel> arrOrder = new ArrayList<OrderModel>();

      String selectedRaw = tblOrderList.getModel().getValueAt(raw, 0).toString();
      String sql = "select item,qty,amount from orderdetails where orderid='"+selectedRaw+"'";
      con = new DBconnector().connect();
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                or = new OrderModel();
                or.setItem(rs.getString("item"));
                or.setQty(rs.getDouble("qty"));
                or.setAmount(rs.getDouble("amount"));
                arrOrder.add(or);

            DefaultTableModel tblModel = new DefaultTableModel();
          // wanted to set ArrayList to table+              
            tblOrderItems.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel());

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Make your `OrderModel` extend `AbstractTableModel` and in `setModel` method use the `or` as the parameter

Comment: Since each `OrderModel` is a row, you need a `TableModel` implementation which can manage these

Comment: @MadProgrammer is correct. You have to create a table model class and then add the rows to that table model and set the model of the jtable to this table model

Comment: i dont havent any abstract classes. cant we do it on this code?

Comment: What is `DbUtils`? Is it a custom Class? if yes then post the code of the method `resultSetToTableModel()`

Comment: `DbUtils` is relevent to rxj2xml.jar.

Comment: where do you find **rxj2xml** and where do you find its documentations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by creating your own `TableModel` which can manage your `OrderModel` class, which represents a individual row in the table...

```
public static class OrderTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    protected static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {"Item", "Qty", "Amount"};
    private List<OrderModel> rows;

    public OrderTableModel(List<OrderModel> rows) {
        this.rows = new ArrayList<>(rows);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Object value = null;
        OrderModel row = rows.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = row.getItem();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = row.getQty();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = row.getAmount();
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Then you can use something like...

```
private void tblOrderListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    int raw = tblOrderList.getSelectedRow();
    OrderModel or;
    String item;
    Double qty, amount, total;

    ArrayList<OrderModel> arrOrder = new ArrayList<OrderModel>();

    String selectedRaw = tblOrderList.getModel().getValueAt(raw, 0).toString();
    String sql = "select item,qty,amount from orderdetails where orderid=?";
    con = new DBconnector().connect();
    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, selectedRaw);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                or = new OrderModel();
                or.setItem(rs.getString("item"));
                or.setQty(rs.getDouble("qty"));
                or.setAmount(rs.getDouble("amount"));
                arrOrder.add(or);
            }
            OrderTableModel model = new OrderTableModel(arrOrder);
            tblOrderItems.setModel(model);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

to simply load the items in a `ArrayList`, which is then passed to an instance of `OrderTableModel` and then applied to the `JTable`

Have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details about using your own custom models.

Have a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details about how you should be using `PreparedStatement`s

Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details about how you can better manage your database (and other) resources

Comment: do you know anything about **rxj2xml.jar**?

Comment: No, and from everything I've seen, it's more trouble then it's worth.  Basically, it takes a `ResultSet` and generates a `TableModel`, you have no further control over it

Comment: @MadProgrammer not good answer I think, then two questions (I don't expect an(y) answer) 1.why answering a questions to OP that never posts an SSCCE, 2. a) int raw should be tested for, if is grather than -1, 2 b.) mouseClicked (all events from 3-5 mouse buttons:-) is very fragile (EDT v.s. performace from/to SQL interpreter), I'd be use popup from right mouse button with Runnable#Thread (for enjoy from SwingWorker) for JDBC

Comment: @mKorbel No, I wouldn't certainly put JDBC calls within the EDT in production, that is true.  It's impossible to provide a runnable example for JDBC based questions and the code gave a good enough idea of what they were trying to do.  `MouseClicked` is not a great choice either, agreeded, a `JButton` on a toolbar or a `JMenuItem` in a `JMenuBar`/`JMenu` or `JPopupMenu` would probably be a better choice, but I have limited time to generate the basic code :P